# Do not start session if app is accessed by a bot

Tags: node.js, express, user-agent, bots

In my Node.js app I initialize session every time new client accesses the app by typical

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: config.secret.session, store: new RedisStore()));
```

which is inside `app.configure`.

Now what can I do if I do not want to filter traffic from bots and not create sessions if I detect that user-agent belongs to a bot by passing user-agent through a regex e.g.

```
/bot|index|spider|crawl|wget|slurp|Mediapartners-Google/i
```

But where do I put this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the file robots.txt like that:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)